# Problem placing error bars at the center of the columns in ggplot()

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, standard-error

I am having a problem with my bar chart- the error bars just appear on the corner of the columns of the grouping variable rather than on them in a centralised way. The code I am using is this:

```
a <- data.frame (Cond = c("In", "In", "Out", "Out"),
                Temp = c("Hot", "Cool", "Hot", "Cool"),
                Score = c(.03, -.15, 0.84, 0.25),
                SE = c(.02, .08, .14, .12))
a.bar <- ggplot (data = a, aes(x = Cond, y = Score, fill = Temp)) +
            theme_bw() + theme(panel.grid = element_blank ()) +
            coord_cartesian (ylim = c(-0.5, 1)) + 
            geom_bar (aes(fill = Temp), stat = "identity", position = "dodge", width = .5) +
            geom_errorbar (aes(ymin = Score - SE, ymax = Score + SE, group = Cond), position = position_dodge(.9), width = .08) +
            labs(y = "Scores" , x = "Cond") +
            scale_y_continuous (breaks = pretty_breaks(n=8)) +
            theme(legend.title = element_blank()) +
            theme(legend.position = "right")
```

The alternative codes I have tried, which I couldn't get to work either, included adding "show.legend = FALSE" to geom_bar(); adding "facet_wrap(~Cond)" plot.a; and introducing "fill = Temp" within ggplot(aes()).
The closest solution was when I changed the position_dodge() argument into:

```
geom_bar (aes(fill = Temp), stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(width = .5)) +
geom_errorbar (aes(ymin = Score - SE, ymax = Score + SE, group = Cond), position = position_dodge(.5), width = .08) +
```

(the rest of the code remains the same). This moved the error bars towards the center of the columns, yet also moved the columns towards each other, eventually making them overlap (see attached figure).
[image: see attached figure]

I would very much appreciate help on this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

Nice question.  A couple of comments:

1. In general, it's a good practice to set all your aesthetics in the original `ggplot()` call, and to override them with different aesthetics only if needed in the individual `geom_xyz()` calls.  In your code, you were setting the fill aesthetic twice, once in `ggplot` and once in `geom_bar`.  You also set the group aesthetic in `geom_errorbar()`.  I don't think any of those things were the ultimate problem, but they did make it harder to debug your code.
2. The main problem was that the `width` argument in `geom_bar` has to match the `position_dodge()` argument inside `geom_errorbar`.  So if you have

   ```
   # ...
   geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge", width = 0.5)
   # ...
   ```

   Then you've got to make sure your `geom_errorbar()` looks like

   ```
   # ...
   geom_errorbar(width = .08, position = position_dodge(0.5)) 
   # ...
   ```

Putting it all together:

```
require(ggplot2)
require(scales)

# define data
a <- data.frame (Cond = c("In", "In", "Out", "Out"),
                Temp = c("Hot", "Cool", "Hot", "Cool"),
                Score = c(.03, -.15, 0.84, 0.25),
                SE = c(.02, .08, .14, .12))

# return plot with everything except error bars
a.bar <- ggplot (data = a, aes(x = Cond, 
                               y = Score, 
                               fill = Temp,
                               ymin = Score - SE,
                               ymax = Score + SE)) +
            theme_bw() + 
            theme(panel.grid = element_blank ()) +
            coord_cartesian(ylim = c(-0.5, 1)) + 
            # manually setting the width means we will have to tell geom_errorbar() about the new width
            geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge", width = 0.5) + 
            labs(y = "Scores", x = "Cond") +
            scale_y_continuous(breaks = pretty_breaks(n = 8)) +
            theme(legend.title = element_blank()) +
            theme(legend.position = "right")

# show plot w/ errorbars, note that argument to position_dodge is same as width supplied above
a.bar + geom_errorbar(width = .08, position = position_dodge(0.5)) 

# save results
ggsave('SO_35424162.png')
```

[image: Final graph]

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add, since I ran into the same issue:

It is very important to specify the `fill` parameter in the main `aes()` and not in the geom_barplot.

Comment: This is incredibly important! I couldn't debug this for a long time (because I thought that `fill` should be irrelevant), but this is crucial and not super intuitive.