# Graph proportion within a factor level rather than a count in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have two categorical variables with multiple levels.  The levels within each variable have different numbers of observations, for example:

```
var1 <- c("Left", "Right", NA, "Left", "Right", "Right", "Right", "Left", "Left", "Right", "Left", "Left","Left", "Right", "Left", "Right", "Right", "Right", "Left", "Left", "Right", NA, "Left", "Left","Left", "Right", NA, "Left", "Right", "Right", "Right", "Left", "Left", "Right", "Left", "Left","Left", "Right", "Left", "Right", "Right", "Right", "Left", "Left", "Right", NA, "Left", "Left")
var2 <- c("Higher", "Lower", NA, "Slightly higher", "Slightly higher", "Slightly higher", "Lower", "Slightly higher", "Higher", "Higher", "Higher", "Slightly higher","Higher", "Lower", "Slightly higher", "Slightly higher", "Slightly higher", "Lower", "Slightly higher", "Higher", "Higher", "Higher", NA, "Slightly lower","Higher", "Lower", NA, "Slightly higher", "Slightly higher", "Slightly higher", "Lower", "Slightly higher", "Higher", "Higher", "Higher", "Slightly higher","Higher", "Lower", "Slightly higher", "Slightly higher", "Slightly higher", "Lower", "Slightly lower", "Higher", "Higher", "Higher", NA, "Slightly lower")
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(var1, var2))
```

I would like to create a graph that plots the proportion of each category of var1 who chose each level of var2.  So for example here, the proportion of group "Left" who chose answer "Higher" (Number of Left people who chose Higher divided by total number of Left people) , next to the proportion of group "Right" who chose answer "Higher" (Number of Right people who chose Higher divided by total number of Right people) for each answer in turn.

I have written the below ggplot code which gives me a graph of the counts of each group for each answer option side by side, but it doesn't give me the proportion so the two groups of Left and Right aren't comparable (as there are different numbers of people in each group.  I should like also to specify particular colours for each group Left and Right if possible...

```
Plot<-ggplot(df, aes(var2))+ 
  geom_bar( aes(fill=var1),position = "dodge")+ 
  labs(x="Left or Right",y="Count")+
  scale_y_continuous()) +
  scale_fill_discrete(name = "Answer:")+ theme_classic()+ theme(legend.position="top")
```

[image]

The second problem I have with this code is that I get a factor level for the NA values I have in my code.  I know I could use na.omit on df in my ggplot code, which works fine for this small dataframe, but my real dataset has multiple columns and if you run na.omit then it removes all rows across all columns with NAs in, which is hundreds of rows of data, which I don't want to do!  Is there a way to remove NAs from specific variables in a dataframe within the ggplot code?

If anyone has any ideas that would be wonderful.  Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can calculate the proportion in each group and then plot. Also you can manually specify colors using `scale_fill_manual`

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df %>%
  na.omit() %>%
  group_by(var1, var2) %>%
  summarise(n = n()) %>%
  mutate(n = n/sum(n)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  ggplot() + aes(var2, n, fill = var1) + 
  geom_bar(position = "dodge", stat = "identity") + 
  labs(x="Left or Right",y="Count")+
  scale_y_continuous() +
  scale_fill_discrete(name = "Answer:")+ theme_classic()+ 
  theme(legend.position="top")  +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("black", "red"))
```

[image]

Here I have removed all the rows with `NA` in it. If you want to do it for only specific columns you can use `filter` with `is.na` to remove those values. So for example, to remove `NA` values only from `var1`, we can do

```
df %>%
  filter(!is.na(var1)) 
  group_by(var1, var2) %>% .....
```

Comment: Hello Ronak, I'm not sure if you will still receive notifications about this post, but just in case, might you be able to advise me how to get error bars onto the proportions displayed in each bar? Thank you so much!

Comment: @Sarah Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35424162/problem-placing-error-bars-at-the-center-of-the-columns-in-ggplot or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44872951/how-do-i-add-se-error-bars-to-my-barplot-in-ggplot2 this will help.

Comment: Thank you!  I have been puzzling over those two posts - i'm trying to calculate the 95% confidence interval for the proportions, and integrate it into your code but I can't work out how.  I've tried to add the code: upperE=(1.96*sqrt(n/sum(n))*(1-(n/sum(n)))/n), lowerE=(-1.96*sqrt(n/sum(n))*(1-(n/sum(n)))/n) into the section of your code where you ungroup the data, but I keep getting errors...  Do you have any thoughts on how to edit it?  Thank you again!

Comment: Perhaps I should ask this in a new question actually, that might be easier :)

Comment: Done! :D https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58343088/how-to-add-95-confidence-intervals-to-graph-of-proportions-of-factor-levels-in