# plot 95% CI for proportions tables in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, visualization, confidence-interval

Concerning error bars, as far as I'm concerned, the most informative one is the **95% CI**. That being said, I want to plot it for my proportions table. **How do I calculate the 95% correctly for a proportion table?** and **plot it** with `ggplot2` ?

- data:

Data contains the proportions of data (number of schools) collected per regions (A:E)

```
## calculate proportions:

region <- data %>% count(Q8) %>% 
  mutate(prop = round((prop.table(n) * 100), digits = 2), sd = round(sd(prop.table(n)), 
  digits = 2), Q8 = fct_reorder(Q8, n)) %>% arrange(n) 

## output
> region
  Q8  n  prop   sd
1  E  3 10.34 0.12
2  C  3 10.34 0.12
3  B  4 13.79 0.12
4  A  9 31.03 0.12
5  D 10 34.48 0.12
```

- Cool. Now I need to calculate the 95% CI. I've tried:

```
region_ci  <- data.frame(DescTools::MultinomCI(region$n, conf.level = 0.95)) %>%
               mutate_if(is.numeric, round, 2)
 
> region_ci
   est lwr.ci upr.ci
1 0.10   0.00   0.29
2 0.10   0.00   0.29
3 0.14   0.00   0.32
4 0.31   0.14   0.49
5 0.34   0.17   0.53
```

- Now I'd like to plot the proportions with error bars. My attempt:

```
 region %>% 
  ggplot(aes(y = prop, x = ordered(Q8), fill = Q8)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 0.3) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin= region_ci$lwr.ci, ymax= region_ci$upr.ci, 
                    width= .1)) + 
  geom_text(aes(label = round(prop, 1.5)),
            nudge_y = 2) + # so the labels don't hit the tops of the bars
  labs(x = "place",
       y = '(%)')
```

- which gives me this:

[image: my pic]

- **Question**: It's clear that I've calculated the CIs wrong. **How can I do that properly?** and **plot the correct error bars** ? I've seen some similar posts, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58343088/how-to-add-95-confidence-intervals-to-graph-of-proportions-of-factor-levels-in), but I'm still not sure on how to correctly calculate the CIs.
- I've also tried [the approach suggested here](https://r-graph-gallery.com/4-barplot-with-error-bar.html), but I've also got weird results. Thanks in adv.
- data:

```
> dput(region)
structure(list(Q8 = structure(1:5, .Label = c("E", "C", "B", 
"A", "D"), class = "factor"), n = c(3L, 3L, 4L, 9L, 10L), prop = c(10.34, 
10.34, 13.79, 31.03, 34.48), sd = c(0.12, 0.12, 0.12, 0.12, 0.12
)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct. The only issue is that the prop values in the **region** data are the percentages (prop*100) but the CI values in the **region_ci** not. So in the ggplot multiply lower and upper ci values by 100 too:

```
 region %>% 
  ggplot(aes(y = prop, x = ordered(Q8), fill = Q8)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 0.3) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin= region_ci$lwr.ci*100, ymax= region_ci$upr.ci*100, 
                    width= .1)) + 
  geom_text(aes(label = round(prop, 1.5)),
            nudge_y = 2) + # so the labels don't hit the tops of the bars
  labs(x = "place",
       y = '(%)'
```

[image]graph output

Comment: oh, thank you! that makes sense! In my case, maybe I should use another parameter for the error bar error than the ```95%``` ? Another would be more suitable perhaps? (since the intervals are huge)

Comment: I think sample sizes are quite small (3 to 10), which can result in wide CI values. Also, the estimated proportions  are relatively large, which also adds more to wider CIs. If possible, you may  consider more data to have larger sample sizes. Alternatively you could do meta analysis combining data from studies. But this is huge work and require more expertise. Hope this could helps

Comment: thank you, @SALAR ! Would another measure be more accurate in this case (small sample size) than the CI ?